# Limit inputs in numberfield

Tags: extjs

How can I make my numberfield have a limit of 5 digits only when I start to type in the field?

I used Ext Js 3.4

This is what I've tried so far:

```
var items = [
    {
        xtype: 'numberfield',
        name: 'fax',
        fieldLabel: 'Fax no',
        allowBlank: false,
        anchor: '90%',
        maxLength: 5
    }
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the documentation for [`maxLength`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.NumberField-cfg-maxLength):

> Maximum input field length allowed by validation

That means, you can enter more than 5 digits, but the field will be marked as invalid in that case.

Furthermore:

> To restrict the maximum number of characters that can be entered into
>   the field use autoCreate to add any attributes you want to a field

That means, by using [`autoCreate`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.NumberField-cfg-autoCreate) you can just add the HTML attribute `maxlength` to the field's underlying input element:

```
{
    xtype: 'numberfield',
    name: 'fax',
    fieldLabel: 'Fax no',
    allowBlank: false,
    anchor: '90%',
    maxLength: 5,
    // set maxlength to 5 on input field
    autoCreate: {tag: 'input', type: 'text', size: '20', autocomplete: 'off', maxlength: '5'}
}
```